# Accessing front facing camera "green screen"?

Tags: android, camera

I developed an android2.3 project ,copy the sample code "CameraPreview" from ApiDemos,and run it on my evo 4g mobile,the back camera was correct ,when switch to front facing camera ,the screen was "green screen",what's the problem?

CameraPreview

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class CameraPreview extends Activity
{
    private Preview mPreview;
    Camera          mCamera;
    int             numberOfCameras;
    int             cameraCurrentlyLocked;

    // The first rear facing camera
    int             defaultCameraId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide the window title.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // Create a RelativeLayout container that will hold a SurfaceView,
        // and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new Preview(this);
        setContentView(mPreview);

        // Find the total number of cameras available
        numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

        // Find the ID of the default camera
        CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++)
        {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
            {
                defaultCameraId = i;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        // Open the default i.e. the first rear facing camera.
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        cameraCurrentlyLocked = defaultCameraId;
        mPreview.setCamera(mCamera);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        // Because the Camera object is a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        if (mCamera != null)
        {
            mPreview.setCamera(null);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {

        // Inflate our menu which can gather user input for switching camera
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.camera_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.switch_cam:
                // check for availability of multiple cameras
                if (numberOfCameras == 1)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage(this.getString(R.string.camera_alert)).setNeutralButton("Close", null);
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                    return true;
                }

                // OK, we have multiple cameras.
                // Release this camera -> cameraCurrentlyLocked
                if (mCamera != null)
                {
                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                    mPreview.setCamera(null);
                    mCamera.release();
                    mCamera = null;
                }

                // Acquire the next camera and request Preview to reconfigure
                // parameters.
                mCamera = Camera.open((cameraCurrentlyLocked + 1)
                        % numberOfCameras);
                cameraCurrentlyLocked = (cameraCurrentlyLocked + 1)
                        % numberOfCameras;
                mPreview.switchCamera(mCamera);

                // Start the preview
                mCamera.startPreview();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * A simple wrapper around a Camera and a SurfaceView that renders a centered
 * preview of the Camera to the surface. We need to center the SurfaceView
 * because not all devices have cameras that support preview sizes at the same
 * aspect ratio as the device's display.
 */
class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    private final String    TAG = "Preview";

    SurfaceView             mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder           mHolder;
    Size                    mPreviewSize;
    List<Size>              mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    Camera                  mCamera;

    Preview(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera)
    {
        mCamera = camera;
        if (mCamera != null)
        {
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    public void switchCamera(Camera camera)
    {
        setCamera(camera);
        try
        {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } 
        catch (IOException exception)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        requestLayout();

        camera.setParameters(parameters);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a
        // wrapper to a SurfaceView that centers the camera preview instead
        // of stretching it.
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null)
        {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0)
        {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);

            final int width = r - l;
            final int height = b - t;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (mPreviewSize != null)
            {
                previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
            }

            // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth)
            {
                final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height
                        / previewHeight;
                child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0, (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            } else
            {
                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width
                        / previewWidth;
                child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2, width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        try
        {
            if (mCamera != null)
            {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        if (mCamera != null)
        {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    }

    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h)
    {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes)
        {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff)
            {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null)
        {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes)
            {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff)
                {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h)
    {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        requestLayout();

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

}


AndroidManifest.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.kiterive.magicmirror"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
    <!-- We will request access to the camera, saying we require a camera
         of some sort but not one with autofocus capability. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MagicMirrorActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The EVO 4G (as of this writing) runs Android 2.2, which lacks support for the 2.3 front-facing camera APIs.  I'm rather surprised your code example runs without tripping an exception for the 2.3 API calls you are invoking.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is a device issue, drivers or something else.
Try testing it on another device.
Also make sure the device is running Android 2.3 or higher, below that it isn't supported.